# Returning the output of a function as the return code of main()

Tags: c++

I'm self-teaching myself here so I don't have a model answer available.

Working through program flow examples and trying to get a number guesser based on binary searching. I've got it to run and catch edge cases successfully but one objective is to have `main()` return the number of guesses made. I refactored the main code into a separate function to make it clearer, but I can't get the return code correct, I suspect it's to do with variable scope but can't figure it out.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int guessNumber(int highest, int lowest, int lAttempts)
{
    int guess = lowest + ((highest - lowest) * 0.5);
    char response = 'a';

    lAttempts++;
    cout << "My guess is " << guess << ", am I correct?" << endl;
    cout << "(y)es/too (h)igh/too (l)ow/(q)uit" << endl;
    cin >> response;

    while (response != 'y' && response != 'h' && response != 'l' && response != 'q')
    {
        cout << "I'm sorry, I didn't understand that" << endl;
        cout << "(y)es/too (h)igh/too (l)ow/(q)uit" << endl;
        cin >> response;
    }

    switch (response)
    {
    case 'y':
        cout << "I guessed correctly after " << lAttempts << " attempts";
        break;
    case 'h':
        highest = guess;
        guessNumber(highest, lowest, lAttempts);
        break;
    case 'l':
        lowest = guess;
        guessNumber(highest, lowest, lAttempts);
        break;
    case 'q':
        cout << "Exiting program";
        break;
    }
    return lAttempts;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Think of a number between 1-100" << endl;

    int highest = 100;
    int lowest = 0;
    int attempts = 0;

    attempts = attempts + guessNumber(highest, lowest, attempts);
    return attempts;
}
```

`cout` returns the correct number of attempts but the program (so `main()`) always exits with 1.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure, because `lAttempts` is copied every time you call `guessNumber`, change signature to `int guessNumber(int highest, int lowest, int& lAttempts)`.

Comment: Or change `guessNumber(highest, lowest, lAttempts);` to `lAttempts = guessNumber(highest, lowest, lAttempts);` This seems a common newbie mistake, not to realise that return values from recursive calls have to be captured too.

Comment: Note that there are only three **portable** return values from `main`: `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `EXIT_FAILURE`. The latter two are defined in `<stdlib.h>`; they provide values appropriate to the OS. Returning `0` is equivalent to returning `EXIT_SUCCESS`. That doesn't mean you can't return other values, but your OS might get confused.

Comment: Thanks all, it's been about a decade since I formally studied recursion so yes, I did miss the capture there.

@fas I've not touched pointers yet, I never understood them in undergrad although they're noxt on my list after arrays.

Comment: @Pete I appreciate that it's not usually appropriate to use the main return in this way, but it ws explicitly part of the problem I was looking at in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing to update your attempt variable within your switch statements.
It should be like this.

```
lAttempts = guessNumber(highest, lowest, lAttempts);
```